# Open highcharts tooltip at a specific point - React typescript highcharts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using React with typescript and I need to open the **Highchart tooltip** as soon as the chart opens up. I need to open it at a specific point.

I know that I need a load function but I am getting error in using **this** keyword in typescript.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution. In Highcharts.Options object, inside chart object use the following code:

```
events: {
        load: function (this: Highcharts.Chart) {
          if (this) {
            const data = this.series.map(s => s.points[s.points.length - 1]);
            this.tooltip.refresh(data);
          }
        }
      },
```

The tooltip will appear as soon as the charts load.

Comment: You can also use the **render** event (instead of **load**). It will display the tooltip as soon as you make any change on the graph.